# "drush sapi-i" command which calls drush_backend_batch_process() fails with "Output is empty"

Tags: search, drush

I am trying to integrate `ElasticSearch` with `Drupal` and till now everything seems to be working except that the command `drush sapi-i` crashes with the output:

```sh
> 'C:/xampp/htdocs/my-project/docroot/vendor/bin/drush' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

In ProcessBase.php line 172:

  Output is empty.


search-api:index [--limit [LIMIT]] [--batch-size [BATCH-SIZE]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] [-y|--yes] [--no] [--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] [-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] [-D|--define DEFINE] [--druplicon] [--notify [NOTIFY]] [--xh-link XH-LINK] [--] <command> [<indexId>]
```

After debugging with `drush sapi-i -d` it seems the call to `drush_backend_batch_process()` causes the issue for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the `vendor/bin` directory I noticed that the `drush` script exists but `drush.bat` or `drush.cmd` were missing, I mean, for some reason even though I executed the `drush sapi-i` command using Git-bash, `Drupal` was still trying to access the `Windows` type of the file (which didn't exist in the source I copied from `Mac`).
so creating the below file manually fixed the issue.

#### `drush.cmd` file:

```
@echo off
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
php "%~dp0../drush/drush/drush" %*
```

#### `drush` file:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd '../drush/drush' && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi

"${dir}/drush" "$@"
```

**Note** that the `drush` script's line ending should be LF (instead of CRLF which `drush.cmd` needs),
so in Git-bash simply `cd` to where your script is and run `sed -i 's/\r$//' my-script-filename` (if your editor can only save with CRLF).